# Powershell for users password date

Tags: powershell

I want to write a basic script for checking for accounts with a password about to expire.

**Here is my script:**

```
$maxPasswordAges = (Get-ADDefaultDomainPasswordPolicy).MaxPasswordAge.Days

$Today = Get-Date

Get-AdUser -Searchbase "MyOU" -filter * - Properties PasswordExpired, AccountExpirationDate, PasswordLastset | Sort-Object  PasswordlastSet 
 Select-Object Name, PasswordExpired, AccountExpirationDate, PasswordlastSet
```

Everything seems fine in the above code, it reads many account types in my OU.
How can I add an additional column to list the "Expiry date" (in how many days that the password will expire)?

For now, I need to do an additional job and run this additional code:

```
where-object {$_.PasswordlastSet} | foreach {($_.Passwordlastset.AddDays($maxpasswordage) - $Today).Days}
```

If I combine the two scripts together, it only show me only "How many days to Expire".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine your two scripts by using a [calculated property](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx) in the `Select-Object` statement:

```
$maxPasswordAges = (Get-ADDefaultDomainPasswordPolicy).MaxPasswordAge.Days 
$Today = Get-Date

Get-AdUser -Searchbase "MyOU" -filter * - Properties PasswordExpired, AccountExpirationDate, PasswordLastset |
    Sort-Object  PasswordlastSet |
    Select-Object Name, PasswordExpired, AccountExpirationDate, PasswordlastSet, @{Name="DaysToExpire";Expression={($_.Passwordlastset.AddDays($maxpasswordage) - $Today).Days}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have check the property ***"msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed"***.

You can calculate that like this:

```
(((Get-ADUser –Identity 'TestUser' -Properties "msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed")."msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed")-(Get-Date).Days)
```

Note: Difference of present date and computed date will give you what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank for improving the code. I'll try to customize it to suite my work.